# How to install package via pip requirements.txt from VCS into current directory?

Tags: python, git, pip

For example, we have project `Foo` with dependency `Bar` (that in private Git repo) and we want install `Bar` into `Foo` directory via `pip` from `requirements.txt`.

We can manually install `Bar` with console command:

`pip install --target=. git+ssh://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage`

But how to install `Bar` into current directory from `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? pip is for installing third-party libraries, which go into site-packages. If you want to put something from Github in the current directory, just clone it directly.

Comment: We have 10+ separate apps every of them in standalone private Git repo and we write an template of basic project into that you can include apps that you want and edit them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to clone the repository, or just donwload the `requirements.txt` file, and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the modules dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "editable" syntax in requirements.txt to install a package from a VCS (eg git)

From the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs):

```
pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomeProject
```